# Install components via Bower without SSL in ASP.NET 5 Starter Web project

Tags: asp.net, proxy, bower, bower-install, visual-studio-2015

Due to corporate proxy issues I am unable to download components via Bower using **https**.

I know that normally you can get around this by adding

> "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com"

to the **.bowerrc** file, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Please note that I haven't had Bower installed locally (as I am not intended to). I got **bower.json** from using the new [ASP.NET 5 starter Web Project](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015) which has popular tools like Grunt and Bower built-in.

I wonder where this file is, or if there is any other way to replace **https** with **http** in the download url?

**Update**
I had to create the **.bowerrc** file manually and placed it inside the project root.

```
{
    "directory": "wwwroot",
    "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com"
}
```

Make sure you have **wwwroot** there as the directory. Doing this the output will now show with **http**.

However, this still doesn't resolve my problem - Bower still cannot download anything, nor can nuget. This is really strange 'cause if I create a normal web project using VS2015, nuget works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .bowerrc file can be located in one of the following:

- Local .bowerrc located in the current working directory
- All .bowerrc files upwards the directory tree
- .bowerrc file located in user’s home folder (%USERPROFILE%)
- bowerrc (without the dot) file located in %APPDATA%/bower/config

But setting the bower registry URL is probably not enough as bower will still need the https protocol in order to fetch package content from Github.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already checked all these places. It doesn't not exist anywhere in my solution; no such file found in `%USERPROFILE%`; I do have `%APPDATA%/bower/` folder but there's no config folder inside.

Comment: Did you try creating a .bowerrc file in on of these locations?

Comment: Actually I just did. I had to also change the directory to `wwwroot` and now the output is showing `http` instead. But I am still not able to download from Bower, nor from nuget (due to some authentication issues within the new starter project). I think it's a different issue though, so I will accept your answer.

Comment: Actually I just did. I had to also change the directory to `wwwroot` and now the output is showing `http` instead. But I am still not able to download from Bower, nor from nuget (due to some authentication issues within the new starter project). I think it's a different issue though, so I will accept your answer.